# On Click function does not execute

Tags: javascript, php, function, onclick

This is a long page, so I will attach the full documentation, but summarize here.  I have a series of map elements that when clicked, are supposed to active a description page.  The relevant code is:

```
    <map id="mapg0" onclick="showPanel('pecheislandrear')" style="position:fixed; z:2">
        <area shape="poly" coords="11,13,13,11,14,11,14,3,12,1,11,0,3,0,1,2,0,3,0,11,2,13,3,14,11,14" alt="" title="Peche Island Rear Range" id="mapg0_1">
    </map>
        <img alt="Peche Island Rear Range" onclick="showPanel('pecheislandrear')" usemap="#mapg0" src="LakeErie1_files/reddot.png" id="imageg0" style="position:absolute; z:1; left:210.258015267px; top:348.347527764px; width:14px;height:14px;">
    <map id="mapg1" onclick="showPanel('stclairflatsfront')" style="position:fixed; z:2">
        <area shape="poly" coords="11,13,13,11,14,11,14,3,12,1,11,0,3,0,1,2,0,3,0,11,2,13,3,14,11,14" alt="" title="St. Clair Flats front Range" id="mapg1_1">
```

The show Panel function is:

```
function showPanel (panelId)
{
    document.getElementById(panelId).style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

Even if I insert an "alert" dialog at the start of this, the alert doesn't show.  But, if I substitute

```
    <map id="mapg0" onclick="alert ('pecheislandrear')"
```

I get the alert, so the "onclick" is acting.  The other piece of this s the panel I wish to active:

```
 <div id="pecheislandrear" class="panelHidden" style="position:fixed;left:50%;margin-left:-136px;top:50%;margin-top:-211px;
        z:1;width:272px;height:422px;">
    <div id="panel0" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:12px;width:272px;
        height:54px;overflow:hidden;">
      <p class="Body panelP-5"><span class="panelTitle">Peche Island Rear Range</span></p>
    </div>
    <div style="position:absolute;left:24px;top:229px;width:232px;height:136px;overflow:hidden;">
      <p class="Normal"><span class="panelDesc">Range lights were 
established off Peche island in 1898. Pile clusters, they were 
repeatedly swept away by ice until 1908 when they were replaced by 
permanent iron and steel structures on cribs. An explosion destroyed the
front range in 1927, and the rear range was leaning so badly it was 
replaced with a modern structure in 1983. The tower was moved to Marine 
City where it can now be seen on the waterfront.</span></p>
    </div>
    <a onclick="var w = window.open(this.href,'_blank','width=1400,directories=yes,location=yes,menubar=yes,resizable=no,
        scrollbars=yes,status=yes,toolbar=yes'); if( w != null ){ w.focus(); }; return false;" href="http://www.lighthousefriends.com/light.asp?ID=165" target="_blank" class="panelOBJ-12 ActiveButton buttonHeight" style="position:absolute;left:84px;top:372px;width:104px;height:21px;">
      <span>Learn&nbsp;More</span>
    </a>
    <img alt="photo" src="LakeErie1_files/pecherear.jpg" onclick="hidePanels()" style="position:absolute;z:2;left:38px;top:73px;width:201px;height:151px;">
 </div>
```

The entire htm is attached for review.[enter link description here](http://gllka.com/LakeErie1.php)  I would appreciate guidance.  A test case with only 2 objects worked.  The longer case with 68 does not and I have been unable to discern the difference.

Comment: your online html works for me! I can click all the items and the assiciated alert pops up!

Comment: but by reviewing your code, just a small hint: for your hiding-function take a look at that: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Comment: Instead of alerts try console.log(panelId) at the start of your showPanel function. This is better for debugging.

Comment: for some reason you have css rules in your js tags. Hence its throwing a error (google chrome console will show you where it is).

Answer (score 0):

if you put `alert()` inside `showPanel` does that run? what if you try this:

```
function showPanel (panelId)
{
    document.getElementById(panelId).classList.remove('panelHidden');
}
```